# SQRTSORT from Vazirani's book on algorithms

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity, sorting

I study the Algorithm book and saw the following exercise. I couldn't solve it. This is not homework, nor exam. Just reading some material on algorithms for preparing entrance exam. Any nice idea or solution would be appreciated.

> Describe an algorithm that sorts an input array $A[1..n]$ by calling a
>   subroutine SQRTSORT(k), which sorts the subarray $A[k+1..k+\sqrt{n}]$
>   in place, given an arbitrary integer $k$ between $0$ and $n-\sqrt{n}$
>   as input. (To simplify the problem, assume that $\sqrt{n}$ is an
>   integer.) Your algorithm is ***only*** allowed to inspect or modify the
>   input array by calling SQRTSORT; in particular, your algorithm must
>   not directly compare, move, or copy array elements. How many times
>   does your algorithm call SQRTSORT in the worst case?

Comment: You can do a bubble sort like operation on blocks of $\sqrt{n}/2$ to do it in $O(n)$ SQRTSORT calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect $l$ greatest values (and collect them in positions $n-l+1,\ldots,n$) from the array by calling SQRTSORT with $k=0$, $k=\sqrt{n}-l$, $k=2\sqrt{n}-2l$, and so on. Therefore, $2\sqrt{n}$ calls are sufficient to find $\sqrt{n}/2$ greatest values from array. Doing this recursively, we sort the array with at most $4n$ calls of SQRTSORT.

A lower bound better than $O(n)$ can not be expected, because some arrays require $cn^2$ transpositions of neighboring entries to be sorted. Note that SQRTSORT acts on $\sqrt{n}$ consequtive entries, and so a permutation caused by SQRTSORT call can be written as a composition of at most $O(n)$ transpositions of neighboring entries.

Comment: This describes procedure SORT(n).

For $t=0$ to $2\sqrt{n}$ perform SQRTSORT($t\sqrt{n}/2$), when finished perform SORT($n-\sqrt{n}/2$) recursively.

Comment: I believe that my comment above is the pseudocode you ask for.

Comment: @user2097, not really clear what you mean!